# Laravel: eloquent select * vs select column

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, model, eloquent

In my **Laravel** API everyone and everywhere written `select *`, even when it does not need to collect all the column data.

Is it better to use eloquent `select` instead, specifying exactly what's needed?

Comment: It depends on use. But if you are looking for what is best, then it would be select column rather than selecting all(*).

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this:

**To select only specific fields you can do something like:**

```
ModelName::all('column1', 'column2', 'column3');
```

**Or using get:**

```
ModelName::get(['id', 'date']);
```

**For Models with relationships:**

```
$model->relation()->only(['column1', 'column2']);
```

**If you need to eager load while selecting specific columns with relationship:**

```
$data = Model::with(array('relation' => function($query)
{
    $query->select('name');

}))->get();
```

You can read more at [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)

Comment: The question is pretty clear, he need to find out what is the best way of doing something: Option A or Option B
Your answer explain correctly several ways of doing those things. But not what is the best way of doing that! You can improve your answer